# CodeIgniter не выводит сообщения об ошибках

Tags: php, codeigniter

Пишу регистрацию, использую фреймворк codeigniter, ошибки связанные с валидацией форм выводятся, а вот ошибки (коллбэки) функций нет :(
Код шаблона:

```
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <? echo form_open(base_url()."user/registration"); ?>
        <?php echo form_error("check_user"); ?>
            <label for="username">Your login:</label>
            <br />
                <input type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" name="username" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <br />
                <input type="email" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" name="email" />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <br />
                <input type="password" id="password" value="" name="password" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <small>Сгененировано за {elapsed_time} секунд.</small>
</body>
```

Код модели, где хранится функция:

```
public function check_user($login)
{
    $this->db->select()->from('users')->where('login', $login);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'Данный логин занят.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Подниму!

апп

Comment: ниче не понял что вы имели ввиду говоря **шибки (коллбэки) функций**

Comment: вы ожидаете что  form_error("check_user"); вызовет функцию `check_user()` ? это не так, это просто напечатает содержимое ошибки валидации именованное check_user, чтобы вызвать check_user вам нужно написать что-то типа

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

Comment: Я в общем создал функцию проверки пользователя, и если логин занят то должно выводиться сообщение об ошибки, типа логин занят. Но он ничего не выводит :(

Comment: так вы сделали как я описал или как-то по-другому ? правило валидации задали ?

Comment: @eicto задал, ничего не изменилось. Функция по-прежнем ничего не выводит если логин занят

Comment: а `check_user()` вообще запускается ?

Comment: @eicto ага, если логин занят он не пускает (не создает пользователя) но и ошибку тоже не показывает, а вот если логин пустой то аккаунт создается.